# Less verbose @Bean

Tags: java, spring, autowired

We use `@Configuration` classes with lots of `@Bean` annotated methods that essentially read like this:

```
@Bean
public TeamContactIndexer teamContactIndexer(GroupService groupService, ContactCrudService contactCrudService, ContactRetrieveService contactRetrieveService) {
    return new TeamContactIndexer(groupService, contactCrudService, contactRetrieveService);
}
```

So this returns a new bean and injects other spring declared things via method arguments into the constructor by name.

The only way I know to reduce verbosity is to annotate the beans with `@Component` and constructor with `@Autowired`.

For many this is perfectly acceptable but I prefer to not litter my code with Spring annotations just to facilitate plumbing and keep a clean separation between completely spring free business logic and plumbing code in @Configuration annotated classes. I treat them as a more type safe, less verbose replacement for what we used to do in xml.

However, wouldn't it be nice if I could just go ...

```
@Bean
public TeamContactIndexer teamContactIndexer;
```

... and have spring figure out that it needs to autowire the constructor of that class (100% spring free) to produce the bean. This is not currently supported in Spring as far as I can see even though it should be quite easy to do as far as I can see. Am I missing something or is there really no way around me micromanaging constructor calls in my `@Configuration` classes (other than littering my code with annotations)? The vast majority of my `@Bean` methods should be easily replaced like this.

**UPDATE**

@bezmax has provided a workable approach here which is to use a component scan annotation.

`@Configuration
@ComponentScan(
    basePackages={"com.github.jsonj.tools"},
    includeFilters = { @Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, value = {JsonParser.class})})
public class JsonParserConfig {
}`

I've used the above to provide a bean definition for a bean without annotations in a library that I use. This replaces the @Bean annotated factory method I had earlier. It's still somewhat verbose but at least you can put in a comma separated list of classes. The default for type is wrong for this usecase so you must specify it; likewise the package defintion is required even though it could be deduced from the class on the filter.

IMHO there is room for an obvious improvement in Spring, which is to provide an annotation that simply takes a comma separated list of classes. So, instead of scanning a package, simply list the bean classes you want initialized. There are probably still a few hairy issues with autowiring via the constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature is implemented in Spring 4.3 (not yet released).

You can read more about that in the [changelog](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-framework/4.3.0.SPR-13777-SNAPSHOT/spring-framework-reference/html/new-in-4.3.html) (see 6.1)

---

**Added:**

As about registering your unannotated classes automatically, there seems to be a flexible way to achieve this using `@ComponentScan` annotation. This annotation allows you to specify a set of include filters, which, when matched on classes, are automatically registered as beans. I had not actually tried using more complex rules with this filter, and it seems that you have several options there (check out the documentation on @ComponentScan) but the easiest one would be something like this:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(
        value = "some.package.path",
        includeFilters = {
                @Filter(type = ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, value = {
                        MyClass1.class,
                        MyClass2.class,
                        MyClass3.class
                })
        })
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
...
```

Comment: I actually played with 4.3 in the last few days. I doesn't quite do what I want. I just allows me to have a constructor in my @Configuration class and set fields from there. I still have to manually call new on all my Bean constructors and manually copy the parameters on that constructor.

Comment: Yes, I have not thought about that. Basically you are trying to manually register a bean having only a class. I will look into that and update my answer if I find any way to do that.

Comment: Just put `@Named` on your bean (if you really don't want spring based annotations) and let spring detect your beans. `@Named` is a standard annotation.

Comment: @bezmax thanks for editing. I like the idea of using component scans like this. This might solve my problem. I'm going to try this.

Comment: @Deinum, the idea for me is that I don't want to have any annotations on my service classes. From my point of view this is cruft and tends to result in an abundance of spring beans that don't actually need to be beans. I'm constantly fighting back circular dependencies in all my spring projects. What I like about Configuration is that it is explicit and physically separates plumbing from logic. What I don't like is the verbosity.

Answer (score 0):

This always bothered me.
Why wouldn't I just use @ComponentScan? Usually I run into this wanting to build a small test application inside a bigger Spring application, I don't enable component scan since it would pull in the world. But then I need to write a @Bean for every class I want to use, and if those have big constructors it becomes messy.

Turns out there is a good alternative nowadays though! @Import also picks up non @Configuration classes, and works quite well :)